# Async task to handle multiple db calls

Tags: android

I have an application with some fragments in it. In one of these fragments i make frequent calls to the db (about 4-5) but they are littered all over the place in the fragment as the user interacts with the screen. For example, when a button is pressed, fetch all records of type b... etc. I know we are supposed to do all database operations preferrable in a seperate thread and i am aware of the AsyncTask and how it can be used to do this.

My question is, since i have calls to the db in more than one method, it doesnt really make sense to create a new async task just to make a db call everytime i need it in different places in the fragment. Is there a way to make multiple db calls in different places in a fragment using a clean and simple implementation of a single async task that handles all of these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
public interface DBRunnable {
    public void executeDBTask();
    public void postExecuteDBTask();
}

private class DBTask extends AsyncTask<DBRunnable, Void, DBRunnable> {
    @Override
    protected DBRunnable doInBackground(DBRunnable...runnables) {
        runnables[0].executeDBTask();
        return runnables[0];
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(DBRunnable runnable) {
        runnable.postExecuteDBTask();
    }
}
```

Which would be called like this:

```
    new DBTask().execute(new DBRunnable() {
        @Override
        public void executeDBTask() {
            // execute your db code here
        }

        @Override
        public void postExecuteDBTask() {
            // run your post execute code here
        }
    });
```

The DBRunnables could be kept in one place to keep the code easier to read and maintain.

Comment: One question, what if i want to have different tasks that get performed based on the db call being made. I mean i would like different OnPostExecute async calls if i read a record vs write a record

Comment: I modified my example to show how onPostExecute can be used as well. If you want to be able to run several DBRunnables at a time you need to pass them in a constructor of the DBTask so that both doInBackground() and onPostExecute() can loop through the runnables. If you do that the parameters and results of AsyncTask are obsolete and can be Void.

Comment: Sory to open this post again, but this is the most suitable answer so here it goes. What is this runnables[0].executeDBTask(); what does it means? and how would you do this?

Comment: postExecuteDBTask() is defined in the interface DBRunnable and implemented by the anonymous class defined in the last piece of code (new DBRunnable() {...}). It's the class that runs your actual db code.